# Error timeout while using OData in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-6.0

My `Program.cs` here:

[image]

My Postman still loading but no responding or error:

[image]

The version of the packages used:

[image]

My controller:

[image]

When I still wait about 1-2 minutes, it throws 500 in VS:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your c drive is out of space

Comment: I don't it's wise to send back results as Queryable because your db session will still be active, which is not good. Using sql queries to get data from db you'll have to open a connection and close it when your done

Comment: @VeronicaAsuquo I think it it conflict between NewstonsoftJson and OData

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following example?

```
services.AddControllers().AddOData((opt, _) =>
    {
       opt.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents("api", EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModelv1());
    });


internal static class EdmModelBuilder
{
    internal static IEdmModel GetEdmModelv1()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
        builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();

        #region UserDto

        builder.EntitySet<UserDto>(nameof(DataListContext.Users))
            .EntityType
            .Page(25, 15);

        var f5 = builder.Function("Get");
        f5.Parameter<int>("key").Required();
        f5.ReturnsFromEntitySet<UserDto>(nameof(DataListContext.Users));

        #endregion

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}


[ODataRouteComponent("api")]
public class UsersController : ODataController
{
    #region ctor

    private readonly ILogger<UsersController> _logger;

    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    private readonly UserManager<AspNetUser> _userManager;

    public UsersController(IMapper mapper,
        UserManager<AspNetUser> userManager,
        ILogger<UsersController> logger)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    #endregion

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 10)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<UserDto> options)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        _logger.LogInformation("{UserUserName} is getting all users", user.UserName);
        return Ok(await _userManager.Users.GetAsync(_mapper, options));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int key, ODataQueryOptions<UserDto> options)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        _logger.LogInformation("{UserUserName} is getting user with id {Key}", user.UserName, key.ToString());
        return Ok(_userManager.Users.Get(_mapper, options).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == key));
    }
}
```